# xargs doesn't work on SUSE

Tags: bash, sed, xargs, suse

> This problem occurs only on [suse](/questions/tagged/suse), it works on ubuntu and even on windows through [babun](/questions/tagged/babun)

My point is to replace a word in several files with another word.

This is what I'm trying:

```
$  grep -Inrs MY_PATTERN src/ | cut -d: -f1 | xargs sed -i 's/MY_PATTERN/NEW_WORD/g'

sed: can't read path/to/a/found/file_1: No such file or directory
sed: can't read path/to/a/found/file_2: No such file or directory
sed: can't read path/to/a/found/file_3: No such file or directory
...
```

Knowing that

```
$  grep -Inrs MY_PATTERN src/ | cut -d: -f1
path/to/a/found/file_1
path/to/a/found/file_2
path/to/a/found/file_3
```

**UPDATE1**

This doesn't work either

```
$  grep -lZ -Irs MY_PATTERN src/ | xargs -0 ls

ls: cannot access path/to/a/found/file_1: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access path/to/a/found/file_2: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access path/to/a/found/file_3: No such file or directory
...

$ ls -al path/to/a/found/file_1 | cat -vet
-rw-r--r-- 1 webme 886 Feb  1 13:36 path/to/a/found/file_1$
```

**UPDATE2**

```
$ whoami
 webme

$ uname -a
 Linux server_vm_id_34 3.0.101-68-default #1 SMP Tue Dec 1 16:21:37 UTC 2015 (ed01a9f) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**UPDATE3**

```
$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.7
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and others, see <http://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/AUTHORS>.


$ xargs --version
xargs (GNU findutils) 4.4.0
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Eric B. Decker, James Youngman, and Kevin Dalley.
Built using GNU gnulib version e5573b1bad88bfabcda181b9e0125fb0c52b7d3b

# My project path /home/users/webme/projects/my_project
$ df -T
 dl360d-01:/homeweb/users/webme nfs   492625920 461336576  31289344  94% /home/users/webme

$ id
 uid=1689(webme) gid=325(web) groups=325(web)

$ mount -v
/dev/vda2 on / type btrfs (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
udev on /dev type tmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,mode=1777)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,mode=0620,gid=5)
/dev/vda1 on /boot type ext3 (rw,acl,user_xattr)
/dev/vdb on /appwebinet type xfs (rw)
rpc_pipefs on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
dl360d-01:/homeweb/users on /homeweb/users type nfs (rw,soft,bg,addr=xx.xx.xx.xx)
dl360d-01:/appwebinet/tools/list on /appwebinetdev/tools/list type nfs (ro,soft,sloppy,addr=xx.xxx.xx.xx)
dl360d-01:/homeweb/users/webme on /home/users/webme type nfs (rw,soft,bg,addr=xx.xxx.xx.xx)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
none on /var/lib/ntp/proc type proc (ro,nosuid,nodev)
```

I don't have `exportfs`, neither I have it in `sudo zypper install exportfs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest keeping it simple:

```
$ grep -lZ -Irs foo * | xargs -0 sed -i 's/foo/bar/g'
```

grep `-l` outputs matching file names only, which is really what you want in this pipeline. `grep -Z` terminates each matching file name with a `NUL`, which `xargs -0` can pick up. This allows for file names with embedded white-space to pass between the grep and the xargs unfettered.

---

```
# show the structure
$ tree
.
└── path
    └── to
        └── a
            └── found
                ├── file_1
                ├── file_2
                └── file_3

# show the contents
$ grep . path/to/a/found/file_*
path/to/a/found/file_1:a foo bar
path/to/a/found/file_2:a foo bar
path/to/a/found/file_3:a foo bar

# try it out
$ grep -lZ -Irs foo * | xargs -0 ls -l
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bishop bishop 10 Feb 13 09:13 path/to/a/found/file_1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bishop bishop 10 Feb 13 09:13 path/to/a/found/file_2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bishop bishop 10 Feb 13 09:13 path/to/a/found/file_3
```

Comment: Updated my post

Comment: `-rw-r--r-- 1 webme 886 Feb  1 13:36 path/to/a/found/file_1$`

Comment: @smarber I'm unable to reproduce. See my edit. Please provide `uname -a`, `whoami`, and either a complete reproduction script including creating the files or actual, unredacted output.

Comment: I've updated my post with new tried things. It's hard to not think that it mainly comes from `suse`

Comment: @smarber I just downloaded [OpenSUSE](https://software.opensuse.org/422/en), put it in a VM, tried the steps above, and they worked for me. The kernel version on the VM is 4.4.27-2. The version on yours is 3.0.101, which is [ancient](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.0). What does `grep --version` and `xargs --version` show? On what kind of file system do these files reside?

Comment: The company has visibly blocked the chat :/.

Comment: You have modern versions of `grep` and `args`, but an old kernel running with an NFS mounted file system. You've demonstrated this works on Ubuntu and Windows, I've demonstrated it works on a modern SUSE. My strong inclination is it's an NFS or NFS+old kernel problem. My suggested workaround: copy the files to a local file system, make the changes, and copy them back. I'd also suggest tweaking your NFS configuration settings: `soft` is dangerous, using the default uid/gid mapping strategies, etc.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>[bishop's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42165381/45375) is the simplest and most robust solution in this case.

*This* answer may still be of interest for (a) a discussion of the `-d` vs. the `-n` options, and (b) how to *preview* the command(s) that `xargs` would execute.</sup>

From what I understand, SUSE uses *GNU* utilities, so you can **use `xargs -d'\n'`**:

```
grep -Inrs MY_PATTERN src/ | cut -d: -f1 | xargs -d'\n' sed -i 's/MY_PATTERN/NEW_WORD/g'
```

`xargs -d'\n'` ensures that **each input line *as a whole* is treated as its own argument (preserving the integrity of filenames with spaces)**, while still **passing as many arguments as possible (typically, *all*) *at once***.

(By contrast, `-n 1` would break arguments by whitespace, and call the target command with 1 argument at a time.)

If you want to ***preview* the command that *would* be executed**, use an aux. `bash` command:

```
grep -Inrs MY_PATTERN src/ | cut -d: -f1 |
  xargs -d'\n' bash -c 'printf "%q " "$@"' _ sed -i 's/MY_PATTERN/NEW_WORD/g'
```

Read on for an explanation.

---

#### Optional background information.

`xargs` has its own option, **`-p`**, for previewing the command(s) to execute *and* prompting for confirmation, but the preview *doesn't reflect argument boundaries* in the way you'd have to indicate them when calling the command directly from the *shell*.

A quick example:

```
$ echo 'hi, there' | xargs -p -d '\n' printf '%s'
printf %s hi, there ?...
```

What `xargs` will *actually* execute is the *equivalent* of `printf '%s' 'hi, there'`, but that is *not* reflected in `-p`'s prompt.

**Workaround:**

```
$ echo 'hi, there' | xargs -d '\n' bash -c 'printf "%q " "$@"' _ printf '%s'
printf %s hi\,\ there
```

The generic auxiliary `bash` command - `bash -c 'printf "%q " "$@"' _`, inserted just before the target command - *quotes* the arguments that `xargs` passes - on demand, only if necessary - in a way that would be required for the *shell* to recognize each as a  *single argument*, and joins them with spaces.

The net result is that **a *shell command* is printed that is the *equivalent* of what `xargs` would execute** (though, as you can see, there is no guarantee that the input quoting style is retained).